# sulog with openSUSE 11.2 (x86_64)

Tags: logs, sudo, opensuse, su

I need to log as much as possible when users a doing `su *`...
Best would be to log all commands especially for the case `root` does something as a user. We can assume `root` would not change this logging behaviour.
I think the matching deal would be something like SULOG in [debian](http://ftp.parisc-linux.org/cgi-bin/man/man2html?5%20login.defs).
How can I get that running?

Answer (score 1):

[`pam_tty_audit(8)`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/pam_tty_audit) was written for exactly this problem:

> **Examples**
>
> Audit all administrative actions.
>
> ```
> session
>
> required pam_tty_audit.so disable=* enable=root
> ```

You could place this is `/etc/pam.d/sudo` for auditing *only* `sudo(8)`, or in `/etc/pam.d/common-session` if you wanted to audit everything `root` does at any console.

Comment: Thanks, sounds fine. I used the `common-session` way. But - where goes the logging to? And - when beeing root it resulted in two entries in `/var/log/messages`: `changed status from 0 to 1` immediately followed by `restored status to 0`. Any more hints?

Comment: @Bastian, no idea on the `/var/log/messages` entries. The logging will go to your `/var/log/audit/audit.log` file -- perhaps `ausearch(1)` can make the logs easier to search or read.